# turn-on-orgstruct++ orgstruct-mode missing

Tags: org-mode

I've been using (turn-on-orgstruct++) for a long time to get some org-mode like functionality in other modes.  However, after a recent update, this has stopped working.  Is there a different way to do this?  Are these functions still supported?

Answer (score 2):

Bah, looks like orgstruct was removed in [version 9.2](https://orgmode.org/Changes.html).

The recommendation is to use [orgalist](https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/orgalist.html) and [outshine](https://melpa.org/#/outshine).